# Write data to one csv row Python

Tags: python, csv

In my py script, I need to write data into a csv file with the result of five columns per row.

```
title:info title title title title    
 one        two  three four  five
 one        two  three four  five
title:info title title title title 
 one        two  three four  five
```

I want to use the `file.write()` method, not the csv module if at all possible.

```
for ip in open("list.txt"):
    with open("data.txt", "a") as csv_file:
        csv_file.write("\r Title:" + ip + ", Title, Title, Title, Title \r")
        for line in open("0820-oRG-apflog.txt"):
            new_line = line.split()
            #search apflog for correct lines
            if "blocked" in new_line:
                if "src="+ip.strip() in new_line:
                    #write columns to new text file & remove headers from lines in files and add commas
                    csv_file.write(ip + ", " + new_line[11].replace("dst=", ", ") + new_line[12].replace("proto=", ", "))
                    try:
                        csv_file.write(new_line[14].replace("dpt=", ", "))
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
```

When I run the script, I get the result:

```
title:info
          title title title title
one
          two three four five
```

I have tried: `csv_file.write('%r\n%r\n%r\n' % (one, three, four))` and variations, but the data just isn't working the way I need it to.

I don't know where my code is wrong. I thought that `.write()` would write data to the same row unless otherwise specified (from previous uses).

**Question**: How do I `.write()` one line of the pattern into one csv row, and still separate the pattern into different rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the trailing newline from the line read first.

Comment: Thanks so much! For some reason I always forget about the trailing newline and run into the same problem!